# django Serializer inserting nothing into database (no errors)

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

As I stated in the title, nothing is bein inserted into my database even though other fields are being inserted. My goal is to take a json post request:

```
{
    "user": "0",
    "total_price":29.60,
    "type":"PENDING",
    "products": [{
        "id_product":"0"
        },{
        "id_product":"1"
        },
        {
        "id_product":"3"
        }
        ]

}
```

I am taking this post rquest and putting it through my serializer to save it to my database. the products field in the json is "a list of foreign keys pointing to the primary key in the Products model.

```
My models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, default="")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users', default='./images/no-account-image.jpg')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,default="") 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id

class Products(models.Model):

    CATEGORY = (
        ('SHIRT','Shirt'),
        ('PANTS','Pants'),
        ('SHORTS','Sorts'),
        ('JACKET', 'Jacket'),
        ('BEANIE', 'Beanie'),
        ('HOODIE', 'Hoodie'),
    )
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True,default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="")
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,default=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,default="")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY,default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', default='./images/No_Image_avaliable.jpg')
    products_remaining = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_id

class Transactions(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        ('SHIPPED','Shipped'),
        ('RETURNED','Returned'),
        ('PENDING', 'Pending'),
    )
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True,default="")
    user =  models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.PROTECT,default="",related_name='user')
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,default=0.0)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE,null=True,default="")
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.transaction_id
```

```
my views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from main.models import Users,Products,Transactions
from main.serializers import UsersSerializer,TransactionsSerializer, ProductsSerializer
from django.core import serializers
from bson import ObjectId
import json

# Create your views here.

@csrf_exempt
def transactionsEndpoint(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        transactions = Transactions.objects.get(product_id='0')
        transactions_serializer = TransactionsSerializer(transactions,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(transactions_serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        transactions_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        print(transactions_data)
        transactions_serializer=TransactionsSerializer(data=transactions_data)
        if transactions_serializer.is_valid():
            transactions_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully",safe=False)
        print(transactions_serializer.errors)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)
    
@csrf_exempt
def productsEndpoint(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        products = Products.objects.filter(product_id__exact='1')
        products_serializer = ProductsSerializer(products,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(products_serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        products_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        products_serializer=ProductsSerializer(data=products_data)
        if products_serializer.is_valid():
            products_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully",safe=False)
        print(products_serializer.errors)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)

@csrf_exempt
def usersEndpoint(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()
        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(users,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        users_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        users_serializer=UsersSerializer(data=users_data)
        if users_serializer.is_valid():
            users_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)
```

```
my serializers.py

from itertools import product
from rest_framework import serializers
from main.models import Users,Products,Transactions

class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields=['user_id','first_name','last_name','email']

class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields=['product_id','cost','description','category','products_remaining']

class TransactionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Users.objects.all())
    products = ProductsSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields=['user','total_price','type','products']
        depth=1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        transactions = Transactions.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product in product_data:
            transactions.products.create(**product)
        return transactions
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM main_transactions;
+----+-------------+---------+---------+
| id | total_price | type    | user_id |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       29.60 | PENDING | 0       |
|  2 |       29.60 | PENDING | 0       |
|  3 |       29.60 | PENDING | 0       |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a many to many relationship between products and transactions, django will have created a separate table. Something like main_transactions_products?

Also, shouldn't the fields under products in your json file be called product_id rather than id_product?